# How to test if correct layout was used in controller using RSpec and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec

I want to write a rspec test that tests if correct layout is used for controller. (Actually I want to test that no layout is used :) ).

I did some googling and also Looked here [Testing rendering of a given layout with RSpec & Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109284/testing-rendering-of-a-given-layout-with-rspec-rails)

But all of this does not work for Rails3.

I have used:

`controller.layout`

and

`controller.class.read_inheritable_attribute(:layout)`

but none of these give me actual layout used.

Do you have any ideas how to get which layout was used for controller?

Answer (score 2):

Try `response.layout`

**EDIT**

Sure enough, `response.layout` no longer works in Rspec2. However you can verify the correct layout was rendered using `render_template` as described on this [Rails Forum thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216851):

```
response.should render_template("layouts/mylayout")
```

As to the second part of your question, I don't see a way of checking for the *absence* of a layout. `response.should_not render_template("layouts/mylayout")` does not appear to work. See [this discussion](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5247-assert_template-wrong-behavior-for-testing-layout-used-to-render-template)

Comment: No there is no such method as `layout` for response object in RoR3 :
NoMethodError (undefined method `layout' for #<ActionDispatch::Response:0x9322ea0>):