# How do I test whether my controller rendered the right layout on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Controller code:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        render 'index', :layout => 'topgun'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How should I test this in the spec?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BooksController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the topgun layout" do
      get :index
      # ???
    end
  end
end
```

I checked [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109284/testing-rendering-of-a-given-layout-with-rspec-rails), but my `response` object doesn't appear to have a `layout` attribute/method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may find the ["Testing Controllers with RSpec"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec) RailsCast and the official [rspec-rails documentation](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/dir/controller-specs) helpful.

Looking at the code for [`assert_template`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template) (which is just what [`render_template`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/matchers/render_template.rb) calls), it looks like you should be able to do

```
response.should render_template("index")
response.should render_template(:layout => "topgun")
```

though I'm not entirely sure that will work.

Comment: I'm not seeing the :layout option in the official docs/source for `assert_template` http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html#M000365

Comment: If you view the source for it there's a case `if options.key?(:layout)`. But now that I look at it a little closer, the `:partial` key might also have to be declared for it to check if there's a layout key.

Also, you appear to be looking at the old rails docs, I was looking at the docs for 3.0 which are on http://api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: We must be looking at different code/pages :) The one I linked has no :layout key. Are they out of date?

Comment: Yea I think the one you were looking at is for 2.3, 3.0 docs are at http://api.rubyonrails.org/. The layout key is still hidden in the source code in the documentation and not a part of the examples, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, I wasn't able to test that the layout **is not** rendered by the controller. `expect(response).to render_template(layout: nil)` always passed no matter what the controller action did. RSpec 2.13.0, Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: @dadooda Does `render_template(layout: false)` (i.e. false instead of nil) work instead?

Answer (score 1):

For **RSpec 3:**

```
expect(response).to render_template(:new)   # wraps assert_template
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/controller-specs