# How to test - with rspec - what template is used when creating an email? (Rails 3.0.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, email-spec

I'm trying to write some tests for emails generated with a mailer class using rspec and email_spec (Ruby on Rails 3.0.7)

I would like to check if the layout used for rendering the email is the layout that was specified in the mailer class.

Any idea on how to do this? I've spent 3 hours searching for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this test?

Comment: If I remember correctly the situation, I had multiple email templates and wanted to test that the emails get sent with the right template

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is a pretty late response. You've probably found a solution already)
I won't be able to update this answer much, but does [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995042/how-do-i-test-whether-my-controller-rendered-the-right-layout-on-rails-3) help? It describes how to check if a layout was rendered. You could make a get request with parameters (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160284/how-to-test-params-passed-into-a-controller-in-rails-3-using-rspec)) then check if the result renders the layout you want it to render.

Comment: Nope unfortunately this does not work with mailer spec

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating a little bit, since you're not *really* checking which template got generated...

However, I just wanted to perform a quick sanity check that the right email is (probably) being generated - so this was good enough for my needs:

```
# In RSpec:
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.subject)
  .to eq I18n.t("name.of.email.subject")

# In MiniTest:
assert_equal I18n.t("name.of.email.subject"),
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.subject
```